# What is "error : invalid use of void expression"?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am trying to create a hexadecimal to base64 converter. I don't know if I am going in the right direction converting binary as I am attempting to do now or if there is a more direct way of converting. Any suggestions on the math of converting or how to code hex to base64 would be very helpful.

On the contrary, I have been receiving the error(The new one since updated code):

```
hexto64.c: In function ‘main’:
hexto64.c:21:17: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
ReVerse(input) = RevHex;
               ^
```

If anybody could help explain what this error means and how to fix
would help greatly! Thank you in advance.

EDIT: So thanks to the few people in the comments, I now understand the error.

Here is my code(Updated):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

char ReVerse(const char *str)
{
    if (*str != '\0')
            ReVerse((str + 1));
    printf("%c", *str);
}



int main()
{
    char RevHex;
    char input[4096] = {0};

    printf("Enter Hexadecimal: ");
    scanf("%s", input);
    RevHex = ReVerse(input);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Last edit: I have found the error in my code. Thank you guys for all the feedback!

Comment: You can't assign to the result of a function call, doubly not when the function returns nothing (`void`).  If a function returns a pointer, you can sometimes write via the pointer, but what you're doing makes little sense.  Simply reversing the LHS and RHS of the assignment won't help; `RevHex` is not a modifiable l-value.  You need to rethink what you're doing.  Maybe just `ReVerse(input)`?  Or you have work to do in the function as well.

Comment: It seems you are trying to assign a (char array) value to a (void) function.

Comment: What is `string`?

Comment: that was me being dumb. I made it a char.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to use the return value of the function `ReVerse()` but this function return `void`. It's "nothing" so you can't assign "nothing" to something. Here you try to put your array `RevHex` to "nothing". This don't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

If your function is just reversing the entered Hexadecimal string then you can do it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

void ReVerse(const char *str) {
    if (*str != '\0')
            ReVerse((str + 1));
    printf("%c", *str); } 

    int main() {
    char input[10] = {0};

    printf("Enter Hexadecimal: ");
    scanf("%s", input);
    ReVerse(input);
    printf("\n");
    return 0; }
```

Here I do not think that this char RevHex[4096] = {0}; is useful. Because you want to reverse the input string. If you implement it like this then this program will work. 
Talking about your program, you are assigning a string value to a void function, that is why it is giving the error.

Comment: Is there a way to make RevHex hold the value of Reverse(input) for later uses?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to "fix" this but trying to assign `RevHex` to a function will throw an error.

Given that ReVerse doesn't return anything, I am not sure what RevHex is for...

Answer (score 0):

The error is this line: `ReVerse(input) = RevHex;`
You can't assign something to a call of void function, you should pass it to the function as parameter.